# Am I growing white cabbage right?

Tags: houseplants, growth, cabbage

I recently got into growing my own veggies.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here I have a base of cabbage which I soaked in water after seeing on YouTube. Is that the right way? What should I be seeing and doing next? Should I change water everyday?

Comment: I've always found cabbage seeds to be cheap enough not to bother with such. Plus, the variety in the supermarket is likely to have been imported from somewhere with different climate, etc., so may not do well in your neighborhood.

Comment: Looks like it is in the normal range of color.

Comment: @blacksmith37 what is normal range and not normal? should I change water daily ?

Comment: This seems like a bizarre approach, and assuming it manages to grow, it will be programmed to bolt, having been a mature head of cabbage who's next role in life is to bolt and set seed, as opposed to a cabbage seed that makes a head of cabbage first.

Comment: As I remember from cutting up several cabbages to make sourkraute, years ago, it looks typical. What is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You are not really growing cabbage, you are trying to get a bit more edible material from what is basically leftovers. And yes, I know that there are a lot of videos with promising titles á la “never buy veggies again” or something like that.

Problem is, you are working with a severely damaged fraction of a plant, so while you may or may not manage to coax it bit more growth out of them, it’s always going to be just a very temporary hail-Mary attempt by the plant to somehow manage to produce a few seeds.

I suggest you consult your YouTube source and see what care advice they include. Changing the water regularly would be a good idea because you will be fighting mold and rot constantly.